# How to fix progressBar and Slider to seek at any desired location in my JavaFX MediaPlayer

Tags: javafx, fxml

I am creating a media player using JavaFX(IntelliJ). Now I am using the Slider as a Progressbar so that I can seek at any desired location. Now whenever I run the Application and start the player, the progress bar works fine along with the media. But when I try seeking at any specific location in the media, it does not work. I am not able to figure out what is wrong here.

### Controller class

```
package com.example.jmediaplayer;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser.ExtensionFilter;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIcon;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MediaPlayer implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane background;
    @FXML
    private Label mediaTitle, appTitle;
    @FXML
    private Button mediaActionButton, mediaNextbutton, mediaPreviousButton, mediaResetButton, openFileButton;
    @FXML
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    @FXML
    private Slider progressSlider;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> speedBox;
    @FXML
    private Slider volumeBar;
    @FXML
    private VBox progressParent, titleParent;
    @FXML
    private HBox controlBar, mediaSelect;
    @FXML
    private MediaView mediaView;
    @FXML
    private ImageView imageView;

    private Media media;
    private javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private boolean isPlaying = false, isSeeking = false;
    private File file;
    private final String[] speeds = {"0.25x", "0.5x", "1x", "1.25x", "1.5x", "1.75x", "2x"};
    private Timer timer;
    private TimerTask task;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        setLayout();

//        mediaActionButton.setGraphic(new FontIcon());
        progressSlider.setMin(0);
        progressSlider.setMax(1);
        progressSlider.setValueChanging(true);
        progressSlider.valueChangingProperty().addListener((observable, wasChanging, changing) -> {
            // If the slider is currently being changed by the user
            // set to true else false
            System.out.println(changing);
            isSeeking = changing;
        });
        progressSlider.valueProperty().addListener((observableValue, number, newValue) -> {
            if (isSeeking) {
                System.out.println("Now I am seeking");
                double newTime = newValue.doubleValue() * media.getDuration().toMillis();
                mediaPlayer.seek(Duration.millis(newTime));
            }
        });
        for (String speed : speeds) {
            speedBox.getItems().add(speed);
        }
        speedBox.setOnAction(this::changeSpeed);

        mediaView.setFocusTraversable(true);
        volumeBar.valueProperty().addListener((observableValue, number, t1) -> mediaPlayer.setVolume(volumeBar.getValue() * 0.01));
    }

    void setLayout() {
        progressBar.prefWidthProperty().bind(progressParent.prefWidthProperty());
        progressBar.prefWidthProperty().bind(progressParent.widthProperty());
        progressSlider.prefWidthProperty().bind(progressParent.widthProperty());

        controlBar.prefWidthProperty().bind(progressParent.widthProperty());

        appTitle.prefWidthProperty().bind(titleParent.widthProperty());
        mediaSelect.prefWidthProperty().bind(titleParent.widthProperty());

        mediaView.fitHeightProperty().bind(background.minHeightProperty());
        mediaView.fitWidthProperty().bind(background.minWidthProperty());
    }

    @FXML
    void changeSpeed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (speedBox.getValue() == null) {
            mediaPlayer.setRate(1);
        } else {
            mediaPlayer.setRate(Double.parseDouble(speedBox.getValue().substring(0, speedBox.getValue().length() - 1)));
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void mediaAction(ActionEvent event) {
        if (isPlaying) {
            cancelTimer();
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            mediaActionButton.setText("Play");
        } else {
            beginTimer();
            changeSpeed(null);
            mediaPlayer.setVolume(volumeBar.getValue() * 0.01);
            mediaPlayer.play();
            mediaActionButton.setText("Pause");
        }
        isPlaying = !isPlaying;
    }

    @FXML
    void mediaNext(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void mediaPrevious(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void mediaReset(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    void beginTimer() {
        timer = new Timer();
        task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                double current = mediaPlayer.getCurrentTime().toMillis();
                double end = media.getDuration().toMillis();
                progressBar.setProgress(current / end);
                progressSlider.setValue(current / end);
                if (current / end == 1) {
                    cancelTimer();
                }
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 100);
    }

    void cancelTimer() {
        timer.cancel();
    }

    @FXML
    void selectFile(ActionEvent event) {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        ExtensionFilter extensionFilter1 = new ExtensionFilter("MP4 files (*.mp4)", "*.mp4");
        ExtensionFilter extensionFilter2 = new ExtensionFilter("MP3 files (*.mp3)", "*.mp3");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extensionFilter1);
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extensionFilter2);
        fileChooser.setSelectedExtensionFilter(extensionFilter2);
        file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        if (file != null) {
            String extension = getFileExtension(file);
            mediaTitle.setText(file.getName());
            media = new Media(file.toURI().toString());
            mediaPlayer = new javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer(media);
            progressBar.setMinWidth(200);

            if ("mp3".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)) {
                mediaView.setVisible(false);
                imageView.setVisible(true);
                String imagePath = "/com/example/jmediaplayer/images/bg-mp3.jpg";
                Image bg_for_mp3 = new Image(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource(imagePath)).toExternalForm());
                imageView.setImage(bg_for_mp3);
            } else if ("mp4".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)) {
                imageView.setVisible(false);
                mediaView.setVisible(true);
                mediaView.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);
            }
            if (isPlaying) {
                mediaAction(null);
            }
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
            progressSlider.setValue(0);
        }
    }

    String getFileExtension(File file) {
        int index = file.getName().lastIndexOf('.');
        if (index > 0) {
            return file.getName().substring(index+1);
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

I tried to use the valueChangingProperty() of Slider to set a changeListener. But it does not work. I must be missing something but can't figure out what.

Comment: There is an example of [slider control of media position](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/playercontrol.htm) in the Oracle tutorial on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

## Fixes & Improvements

There are a few things that can be improved upon in your code. See example at the end of the answer for the code showing the improvements discussed below.

### `ProgressBar` and `Slider`

You currently have a `ProgressBar` and a `Slider` visually showing the time of the media player. I'm not entirely sure why you have both, but I recommend using one **or** the other.

If you have both for visual reasons, then I would suggest:

1. Seeing if you can style either the `ProgressBar` or `Slider` to give the visuals you want.
2. If styling alone does not work, then see if you can subclass one of their default skins to customize them.
3. If both styling and subclassing an existing skin fails you, then consider writing a completely new skin implementation. Of course, at this point, I would start to consider just creating a custom control (which involves writing a skin implementation) for this.

The rest of this answer assumes `Slider` was chosen over `ProgressBar`.

### Updating `value` with a `Timer`

You are currently using a `Timer` to periodically query the media player's `currentTime` and update the slider's `value` accordingly. This approach has a few problems:

1. You are not guaranteeing the slider's `value` will always be fully up-to-date.
2. You are querying state updating by the *JavaFX Application Thread* from a background thread without establishing an explicit *happens-before* relationship between the two threads. This means you may not even see the latest values, even if they were set.
3. Using a background thread for this is unnecessary and just complicates things.

The `currentTime` property will be updated periodically already. All you have to do is add a listener to it and have that listener update the `value` property.

### Seeking

Having a listener on the `value` property seek the media player is a good idea. We just need to ensure that we don't seek **every** time the property changes. Unfortunately, using the `valueChanging` property for that is not going to work. At least not on its own. The problem is that the `valueChanging` property only becomes true when the user presses the mouse on the thumb. But the user can also change the value by clicking somewhere on the track, and we need to seek in that case as well.

To solve this, have the `value` property's listener check a `boolean` flag before seeking; only seek if it is not set. The flag will be set whenever the `value` is being changed programmatically, such as by the `currentTime` property's listener (mentioned in the previous section). This effectively makes it so the `value` property listener assumes the user is seeking unless told otherwise.

Additionally, it would likely provide a better user experience if the media player was paused while the user is actively seeking (i.e., while dragging the thumb of the slider). This part **can** be implemented via the `valueChanging` property.

---

## Example

Here's an example with the improvements discussed above. This example only includes a "time slider". It does not include any of the other playback controls (e.g., play/pause button, speed box, etc.). Note you have to modify the example to give the `Media` a valid URI if you want to run it.

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {

    private Slider timeSlider;

    private Media media;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private boolean updatingValue;
    private boolean wasPlaying;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        timeSlider = new Slider(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        timeSlider.valueProperty().addListener(this::onValueInvalidated);
        timeSlider.valueChangingProperty().addListener(this::onValueChangingChange);

        // FIXME: Replace "..." with real media URI
        media = new Media("...");

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
        mediaPlayer.currentTimeProperty().addListener(this::onCurrentTimeChange);

        var root = new StackPane(new MediaView(mediaPlayer), timeSlider);
        StackPane.setAlignment(timeSlider, Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
        StackPane.setMargin(timeSlider, new Insets(10));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void onValueInvalidated(Observable obs) {
        if (!updatingValue) {
            double ms = media.getDuration().toMillis() * timeSlider.getValue();
            mediaPlayer.seek(Duration.millis(ms));
        }
    }

    private void onValueChangingChange(
            ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> obs, Boolean wasValueChanging, Boolean isValueChanging) {
        if (isValueChanging) {
            if (mediaPlayer.getStatus() == MediaPlayer.Status.PLAYING) {
                wasPlaying = true;
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            } else {
                wasPlaying = false;
            }
        } else if (wasPlaying) {
            mediaPlayer.play();
        }
    }

    private void onCurrentTimeChange(
            ObservableValue<? extends Duration> obs, Duration oldTime, Duration newTime) {
        if (!timeSlider.isValueChanging()) {
            updatingValue = true;
            try {
                double value = newTime.toMillis() / media.getDuration().toMillis();
                timeSlider.setValue(value);
            } finally {
                updatingValue = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not tested, but isn’t it cleaner to invert the logic here? Ie set a flag before updating the slider value programmatically and unset it after, then only respond to slider value changes if the flag is unset. The problem with using mouse event filters/handlers, as ever, is that the code fails with other behaviors (eg key presses).

Comment: Regarding `valueChanging` and whether that is a bug: my understanding is that this is the intended behavior. Dragging the thumb results in a lot of rapid changes to the value, and I think the intention of the API is to allow the opportunity to ignore those until a value is “committed” by releasing the thumb, if so desired. (Respond to value changes only if `valueChanging` is false, and respond to `valueChanging` changing from true to false by querying the value and responding then.)

Comment: In that case, I might consider the intended behavior of `valueChanging` to be an "API bug". If you're going to have that property, I believe it should be able to be used to distinguish between any and all changes done by the user explicitly versus programmatically. I'm not sure about your first comment. How are you distinguishing the `value` property changing because the user changed the value versus because the media player's `currentTime` property changed in that scenario?

Comment: A click on the track represents a single user gesture, resulting in one change in the `value` property. Dragging the thumb is a single gesture, resulting in multiple (likely rapid) changes. So I think the API design is intended to distinguish the case where "the value is in the process of continual changes". I'm not convinced it's the best API design; perhaps better would just be the `valueProperty()` as it currently is and an action event which is fired by either clicking on the track or releasing the drag (similar to an action event on a text field representing a "commit").

Comment: For the first comment I had in mind: `mediaPlayer.currentTimeProperty().addListener((ob, o, n) -> { updatingSlider = true; slider.setValue(...); updatingSlider = false;});` and `slider.valueProperty().addListener((ob, o, n) -> { if (!updatingSlider) { ... } });`

Comment: I'll post an alternative answer if I can find a suitable video file...

Comment: I think I see what you mean. It works, though the thumb will keep moving even if you continue to "hold" it after dragging it somewhere. That said, if you move again the thumb will jump to the mouse's horizontal location (and seeks), and if you release the mouse, it's not like it suddenly seeks back to where the mouse was. So, given the benefits you mentioned regarding mouse event filters not handling other input events, I'll update my answer.

Comment: You could also place a `! slider.isValueChanging()` guard in the listener on the media player's current time. Or perhaps it's better to pause playback when `valueChanging` becomes true, and restore its previous state when it becomes false?

Comment: Updated answer. Is it what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking.